# When does time go and when does time stop at Pathologic?

Tags: pathologic

In [Pathologic](http://store.steampowered.com/app/384110/) all the events are connected to in-game time. But what the in-game time is connected to? It looks like the time goes quicker when you walk and slower when you talk. When you are in menu it clearly stops.

I would like to know how exactly fast time goes during different actions, like: walking, talking with npc, trading, staring on the map or diary, just staying in one place and staring to the street view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time moves at the same rate for any action, except for pausing the game (ESC button), talking to people, and bringing up your map or quest/adherents screen, during which time stops completely. I'm pretty sure it stops when you're bartering to someone as well.

Obviously, time speeds up when you sleep.